# Open an encryption key to create a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, sql-view

I have two sql tables with columns, EncryptedSSN. Normally, I use the following,

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCertificate; 

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Customers
    LEFT JOIN Sales ON 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR, DecryptByKey(Sales.EncryptedSSN)) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DecryptByKey(Customers.EncryptedSSN))
```

Problem is, I want to make a view using the same left join as above, but it errors on the Open keyword. Can I get around this?

Comment: A view can only be a single query statement (SELECT), nothing more than that.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to join the columns without decrypting them?

Comment: Shouldn't symmetric encryption yield the same encrypted values for the same source values?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I'm not getting any results where I'd expect them when I just use Sales.EncryptedSSN = Customers.EncryptedSSN

Comment: @TT. Perhaps there is just a problem with my data...

Comment: That's hard to say for me. You should know that VARCHAR without a length specification is a VARCHAR(30) by default. But even that should work then. I can't really answer as I haven't ever created a view that required a join on encrypted data.

Comment: Does it make sense that even though the decrypted data looks identical, the encrypted data looks different? They are both encrypted using `EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSNKey'), 'strSocSecNumberUnencrypted')` - Would Key_GUID create differing strings?

Comment: Okay the values are definitely different, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: Do you think a stored procedure would do instead of a view? Ok, not as practical in terms of joining with other tables/views, but could get you the result by using the statement you now have. I'm guessing there is some sort of salt, or another data item, encrypted along with the data...

Comment: @TT. I think I might have to do something like that, and just store the result. I'd like to understand why the encrypted values are different though.

Comment: I would too, I think I'm out of my league with this one. I have a similar project with encryption coming in the near future, but haven't had the chance to delve deep into this. Too bad no one else chimed in...